# GET request works with CURL but not as a URL

Tags: php, curl, twilio-api

Here are two `GET` requests.  The first one using `CURL` in `php` works, but the second one generated by an `HTML form` receives an error from the response server.

**The first (working) is a GET request using CURL**

**1.**

```
curl 'https://api.authy.com/protected/json/phones/verification/start' \
-d api_key=my_key\
-d via=sms \
-d phone_number=my_number\
-d country_code=my_code
```

**The second (not working) is a GET request URL like one generated from an html form `<form method='get'>`**

**2.**

`https://api.authy.com/protected/json/phones/verification/start?api_key=my_key&via=sms&phone_number=my_number&country_code=my_code`

The error message from the response server when using the second one is:

`{"message":"Requested URL was not found. Please check http://docs.authy.com/ to see the valid URLs","success":false,"errors":{"message":"Requested URL was not found. Please check http://docs.authy.com/ to see the valid URLs"},"error_code":"60000"}`

**Question**

What is the difference between second GET request compared to the CURL GET request? They look to me like they are identical.

Comment: Are you sure that this is really the same? According to the documentation, `-d` builds a `POST` request

Comment: -d send as POST, the second not. Another difference may be, if your params (I assume, you posted placeholders) contain special characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the documentation at https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification, you should use a `POST` request to use that API, and that is what the `-d` option of cURL does.

In your second call, you send a `GET` request, and according to the documentation and the error message, that is not successful